# Merge two data sets using AWK

Tags: shell, merge, awk

I have 2 data files: `file01` and `file02`. In both data sets fields are: (i) an identificator; (ii) a numeric reference; (iii) longitude; and (iv) latitude.
For each row in `file01`, I want to seach the data in `file02` with the same numeric reference and then, find the identificator in `file02` which is nearest to the identificator in `file01`.

I can get this if I pass manually the values from `file01` to the awk program using the following code:

```
awk 'function acos(x) { return atan2(sqrt(1-x*x), x) }
BEGIN {pi=3.14159;
       ndist=999999999.1;
       date=1001;
       lo1=-1.20; lg1=lo1*(pi/180);
       la1=30.31; lt1=la1*(pi/180)
           }
{if($2==date) {ws=$1;
               lg2=$3*(pi/180);
               lt2=$4*(pi/180);
               dist= 6378.7 * acos( sin(lt1)*sin(lt2) + cos(lt1)*cos(lt2)*cos(lg2-lg1) );
               if(dist < ndist) {ndist=dist; ws0=ws}}}
END {print(ws0,ndist)}' file02
```

As you see, `date`, `lo1` and `la1` in the `BEGIN` statement are the values in the 1st row of `file01` (see below for data files). My question is if I could do that at once, so each time I read a row in `file01`, I get the nearest identificator and the distance and append to the row data in `file01`. I do not know if some shell command could achieve this in a easier way, maybe using a pipe.

An example of these two data files and the desired output are:

=== file01 ===

```
A 1001 -1.2 30.31
A 1002 -1.2 30.31
B 1002 -1.8 30.82
B 1003 -1.8 30.82
C 1001 -2.1 28.55
```

=== file02 ===

```
ws1 1000 -1.3 29.01
ws1 1001 -1.3 29.01
ws1 1002 -1.3 29.01
ws1 1003 -1.3 29.01
ws1 1004 -1.3 29.01
ws1 1005 -1.3 29.01
ws2 1000 -1.5 30.12
ws2 1002 -1.5 30.12
ws2 1003 -1.5 30.12
ws2 1004 -1.5 30.12
ws2 1005 -1.5 30.12
ws3 1000 -1.7 29.55
ws3 1001 -1.7 29.55
ws3 1002 -1.7 29.55
ws3 1003 -1.7 29.55
ws3 1004 -1.7 29.55
ws3 1005 -1.7 29.55
ws4 1000 -1.9 30.33
ws4 1001 -1.9 30.33
ws4 1002 -1.9 30.33
ws4 1003 -1.9 30.33
ws4 1004 -1.9 30.33
ws4 1005 -1.9 30.33
```

=== output file ===

```
A 1001 -1.2 30.31 ws4 67.308
A 1002 -1.2 30.31 ws2 35.783
B 1002 -1.8 30.82 ws4 55.387
B 1003 -1.8 30.82 ws4 55.387
C 1001 -2.1 28.55 ws1 85.369
```

**EDIT #1:** Considering the suggestion by @Eran, I wrote the following code:

```
join -j 2 < (sort -k 2,2 file01) < (sort -k 2,2 file02) |
awk 'function acos(x) { return atan2(sqrt(1-x*x), x) }
     BEGIN {pi=3.14159}

     {if (last != $1 $2)
         {print NR, id,r,lon,lat,ws0,ndist;
          last = $1 $2;
          ndist=999999999.1

         } else {

          lg1=$3*(pi/180);
          lt1=$4*(pi/180);
          lg2=$6*(pi/180);
          lt2=$7*(pi/180);
          dist= 6378.7 * acos( sin(lt1)*sin(lt2) + cos(lt1)*cos(lt2)*cos(lg2-lg1) );
          if(dist< ndist) {ndist=dist; ws0=$5}
          id=$2;r=$1;lon=$3;lat=$4

          }
     }'
```

The output from this script is:

```
1      
4  A 1001 -1.2 30.31 ws4 67.3078
7  C 1001 -2.0 28.55 ws3 115.094
11 A 1002 -1.2 30.31 ws2 35.7827
15 B 1002 -1.8 30.82 ws4 55.387
```

**EDIT #2**: Using athe suggestion of @Dennis (with some modifications) I have got the desired output. The awk script is as follows:

```
awk 'function acos(x) { return atan2(sqrt(1-x*x), x) }
     BEGIN {pi=3.14159}
     NR==FNR {c++; a1[c]=$1;a2[c]=$2;a3[c]=$3;a4[c]=$4; next}
             {d++; b1[d]=$1;b2[d]=$2;b3[d]=$3;b4[d]=$4}

     END {
     for(k=1;k<=c;k++) {
         lg1=a3[k]*(pi/180);
         lt1=a4[k]*(pi/180);
         ndist=999999999.1;
         for(l=1;l<=d;l++) {
             if(b2[l]==a2[k]) {kk=b2[l];
                lg2=b3[l]*(pi/180);
                lt2=b4[l]*(pi/180);
                dist= 6378.7 * acos( sin(lt1)*sin(lt2) + cos(lt1)*cos(lt2)*cos(lg2-lg1) );
                if(dist<ndist) {ndist=dist; ws0=b1[l]}
             }
         }
         print a1[k],a2[k],a3[k],a4[k],ws0,ndist
     }
    }' file01 file02
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read your values from file01 into one or more arrays. You can use `getline` in the `BEGIN` block or the canonical way is to use a `FNR == NR` loop as one of the main blocks.

```
FNR == NR {array[$1] = $1; ...; next } # read file01 into some arrays
{ for (item in array) { ... }     # process each item in the array(s) against each line in file02
```

Your script would be invoked as `awk '...' file01 file02`

Instead of indexing the arrays by field values, you could index them with a counter `array1[c] = $1; array2[c] = $2; c++` and iterate with a counter instead of using `in`: `for (i=0; i<c; i++)`.

Of course, you should choose meaningful array names.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting challenge. Since you have to read in file02 first and store in info in a data structure, I'd lean first to Perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# see http://perldoc.perl.org/Math/Trig.html
use Math::Trig qw(great_circle_distance deg2rad);
sub NESW {deg2rad($_[0]), deg2rad(90-$_[1])}

# read file02
my %data;
my $file2 = 'file02';
open my $fid, '<', $file2 or die "can't read $file2: $!\n";
while (<$fid>) {
    my ($id, $ref, $long, $lat) = split;
    push @{$data{$ref}}, [$id, $long, $lat];
}
close $fid;

$, = " ";

# process file01
my $file1 = 'file01';
open $fid, '<', $file1 or die "can't read $file1: $!\n";
while (<$fid>) {
    my ($id, $ref, $long, $lat) = split;
    my @here = NESW($long, $lat);
    my $min = 99_999_999;
    my (@min_id, $dist);

    while (my ($key, $listref) = each %data) {
        next unless $key == $ref;

        foreach my $trioref (@$listref) {
            my ($other_id, $other_long, $other_lat) = @$trioref;
            my @there = NESW($other_long, $other_lat);
            $dist = great_circle_distance(@here, @there, 6378.7);
            if ($dist < $min) {
                $min = $dist;
                @min_id = @$trioref;
            }
        }
    }

    printf "%s %d %s %s %s %6.3f\n", $id, $ref, $long, $lat, $min_id, $min;
}
close $fid;
```

This outputs

```
A 1001 -1.2 30.31 ws4 67.308
A 1002 -1.2 30.31 ws2 35.783
B 1002 -1.8 30.82 ws4 55.387
B 1003 -1.8 30.82 ws4 55.387
C 1001 -2.1 28.55 ws1 93.361
```

I notice the "C" distance is different from what you suggest it should be.

Comment: Thank you @glenn for your help. I am not familiar with perl, so I need more time to review your suggestion, but it seems a great help.

Answer (score 1):

To do it at once, run

```
join -j 2 <(sort -k 2,2 file01) <(sort -k 2,2 file02)
```

And pipe it to a awk which on every change in reference do the calc:

```
gawk '{if (last != $1 $2) {calc_nearest_on_array; last=$1 $2; add_point_to_array} else {add_point_to_array}}'
```

Comment: your attemp looks promising. However, I have a problem when try to do it: since I calculate the nearest each time `last != $1 $2` and given that the when reading the 1st row `last` is different from `$1` and `$2`, I do not get the nearest point for the 1st row and I have no print for the last row in `file01`. Please, see my EDIT on question for review my code.

Comment: You are correct. I wrote a 'conceptual' awk to demonstrate the idea. In order to print the last line you need to use the END clause.

Answer (score 0):

TXR:

```
@(do
   (defvar pi 3.1415926535)
   (defvar earth-radius 6378.7)
   (defun rad (deg) (/ (* deg pi) 180))
   (defun sphere-distance (lat0 lon0 lat1 lon1)
     (let ((lat0 (rad lat0)) (lat1 (rad lat1))
           (lon0 (rad lon0)) (lon1 (rad lon1)))
       (* earth-radius (acos (+ (* (sin lat0) (sin lat1))
                                (* (cos lat0) (cos lat1) (cos (- lon1 lon0)))))))))
@(next "file01")
@(collect)
@id @ref @lon0 @lat0
@  (filter :tonumber lon0 lat0)
@  (next "file02")
@  (bind (min-dist ws) (1e99 nil))
@  (collect)
@ws1 @ref @lon1 @lat1
@    (filter :tonumber lon1 lat1)
@    (do (let ((d (sphere-distance lat0 lon0 lat1 lon1)))
           (cond ((< d min-dist)
                  (set min-dist d)
                  (set ws ws1)))))
@  (end)
@  (do (format t "~a ~a ~0,2f ~0,2f ~a ~0,3f\n" id ref lon0 lat0 ws min-dist))
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ txr dist.txr
A 1001 -1.20 30.31 ws4 67.308
A 1002 -1.20 30.31 ws2 35.783
B 1002 -1.80 30.82 ws4 55.387
B 1003 -1.80 30.82 ws4 55.387
C 1001 -2.10 28.55 ws1 93.361
```

Comment: what is a TXR script? My debian distribution have no TXR.

Comment: TxR home page is: http://www.nongnu.org/txr . There is no Debian package maintainer.